# AutoIT & VBS - Adding PC to a Domain from the Windows lock screen

Tags: windows, vbscript, autoit

I am working on an AutoIT (& VBS) script to join a PC to the domain from the Windows (7) lock screen. I have replaced the Utilman.exe in the system32 folder with my script. When the ease of access button is clicked on the Windows lock screen my Autoit GUI comes up and displays the IP, PC name, and has a few self help buttons for end users.

One of the buttons on my GUI calls a function to rejoin a pc to the domain after it has fallen off the domain. My issue is, from the lock screen, the Join Domain button runs but does not join the PC to the domain. Even after reboot. If I login to an Admin account and click the same Join Domain button the PC gets added to the domain without issue. This has me rather confused as my script runs as the SYSTEM user from the lock screen. Any input or advice on this issue is greatly appreciated!

My function used to joint the PC to the domain is below. It works when logged into an admin account but does not join the PC to the domain from the Windows lock screen

Edit: the domain script came from this example:
http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/ad/computer/scr_5.asp

And the idea to run the script from the lock screen came from the example below. Ive replaced Utilman.exe with my script, naming my script Utilman.exe and placed it in the system32 folder
https://www.technibble.com/bypass-windows-logons-utilman/

```
Func joinDomain()

$file = FileOpen("C:\IT\joinDomain.vbs", 1)
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const JOIN_DOMAIN = 1')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const ACCT_CREATE = 2')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const ACCT_DELETE = 4')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const WIN9X_UPGRADE = 16')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED = 32')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const JOIN_UNSECURE = 64')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const MACHINE_PASSWORD_PASSED = 128')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const DEFERRED_SPN_SET = 256')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Const INSTALL_INVOCATION = 262144')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' ')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'strDomain = "Domain.net"')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'strPassword = "joinDomainPassword"')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'strUser = "SDSUser"')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' ')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' ')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'Set objComputer = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & _')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name=''" & _ ')
    FileWriteLine($file, '  strComputer & "''") ')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' ')
    FileWriteLine($file, 'ReturnValue = objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup(strDomain, _')
    FileWriteLine($file, ' strPassword, strDomain & "\" & strUser, NULL, _')
    FileWriteLine($file, '  JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE)')
FileClose($file)
Sleep(100)

    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & 'wscript.exe C:\IT\joinDomain.vbs', @SystemDir, @SW_HIDE)

sleep(1000)
FileDelete("C:\IT\joinDomain.vbs")
messageBox()
EndFunc
```

> Here is a full AutoIT version of the VBS script above. It works fine when logged in as an admin but I get an error 2717 when I call
>    the same function from the Windows lock screen.

```
                                                                                                                  Const $JOIN_DOMAIN = 1
Const $ACCT_CREATE = 2
Const $ACCT_DELETE = 4
Const $WIN9X_UPGRADE = 16
Const $DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED = 32
Const $JOIN_UNSECURE = 64
Const $MACHINE_PASSWORD_PASSED = 128
Const $DEFERRED_SPN_SET = 256
Const $INSTALL_INVOCATION = 262144

Const $DOMAIN = "Domain.net"
Const $ADMINKENNWORT = "Password"
Const $ADMIN = "SDUser"
Const $COMPUTER = @ComputerName

$objComputer = ObjGet("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & $COMPUTER & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" & $COMPUTER & "'")
$Result = $objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup($DOMAIN, $ADMINKENNWORT, $DOMAIN & "\" & $ADMIN, "", $JOIN_DOMAIN + $ACCT_CREATE)
If ($Result <> 0) Then
    MsgBox(0, "Error Joining the Domain", $COMPUTER & " Error code: " & $Result )
EndIf
```

Comment: Here is a full AutoIT version of the VBS script above. It works fine when logged in as an admin but I get an error 2717 when I call the same function from the Windows lock screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the wmi.here is an UDF.

```
Func _SetWorkGroup($WorkGroup)
;================================
;Usage：_SetWorkGroup(WprkGroup Name)
;Make By Sanhen
;================================
Local $objNetwork, $strComputer

$objNetwork = ObjCreate("WScript.Network")
$strComputer = $objNetwork.ComputerName
$objComputer = ObjGet("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & _
        $strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" _
         & $strComputer & "'")
Return $objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup($WorkGroup)
EndFunc   ;==>_SetWorkGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just running into a rights issue. Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
#RequireAdmin
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding #RequireAdmin did not resolve the issue. Still works great when logged into an account, but not from the Windows lock screen. When I pull the user name, on the locks screen via @UserName, it shows the script is running as SYSTEM.